# Proof that the degree of every vertice in a Minimum Spanning Tree (MST) is constant (i.e. not dependent on the number of vertices $n$)

Tags: graph-theory, proof-writing, trees

Given a set of points S in $\mathbb{R}^2$ we have a MST of these points.

I want to proof that every vertice has a degree in $\mathcal{O}(1)$, i.e. it does not depend on the number of vertices in the MST. Intuitively i can see that this has to be true since otherwise there would be cycles and a lot of edges and therefore probably not a MST.

Any hint is appreciated!

Comment: A tree with $n$ vertices has $n-1$ edges. So this isn't necessarily true, as there could be one vertex with degree $n-1\in\mathcal O(n)$.

Comment: @Math1000 Not in the planar Euclidean minimum spanning tree version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint: Suppose we have a minimum spanning tree $T$, take a vertex $v$, with two other vertices $v_1,v_2$ adjacent to $v$, and suppose the angle $\angle v_1 v v_2$ is $\alpha$.

Since $v$ is adjacent to $v_1$ and $v_2$ in the MST, we must have $d(v,v_1) + d(v,v_2)$ less than both of the alternatives $d(v,v_1) + d(v_1,v_2)$ or $d(v,v_2) + d(v_1,v_2)$. Therefore, we just need to argue that (if $\alpha$ is small enough) we'll have that $d(v_1,v_2)$ is smaller than the maximum of $d(v,v_1)$ and $d(v,v_2)$.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I can follow your idea just until the last sentence which doesn't make sense to me yet. What conclusion do I get out of the fact that at a small angle $d(v_1,v_2)$ is smaller than max{$d(v,v_1),d(v,v_2)$} and how can i formulate this in terms of the degree of each vertice?

Comment: @rndmusr If you can show that the minimum spanning tree must have $\alpha$ greater than some fixed bound (like for example $60$ degrees) for every pair of neighbors of a vertex, then there cannot be more than $\frac{360}{60} = 6$ neighbors for that vertex, which gives a constant bound on the degree.

Comment: Oh now it makes sense. Thanks a lot. I read about several constant bounds to this problem in the range of max. 4 to 7 degrees (without proofs I could understand) of the vertices in a EMST. Is 6 the (currently) proofen bound?

Comment: @rndmusr You certainly can get a set of points to have a MST with a vertex of degree $6$ in the plane, but there might also be one with lower max degree, so it depends on how the question is phrased..